# Strange crash on IE8 Ajax

Tags: internet-explorer-8

On my website, I experience a strange IE8 bug, where IE8 crashes with message:

"Microsoft Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."

It happens for instance on the following site, when clicking on "show more".

http://goout.cz/clubbing/trance/prague

The site actually does a AJAX request and replaces part of the document. Other browser without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously IE had some strange problem with JQuery and accessing by ID as **$("#id")**. Replacing the method with **document.getElementById** did the trick.